# Type provided must be an Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following setup

```
public enum Color
{
      Red,
      Green,
      Blue
}

public void ToCombo<T>(this T enumType)
{
    var v = Enum.GetValues(enumType.GetType()); <-- Exception raised
}
```

while calling the extension method

```
typeof(Color).ToCombo();
```

i get the following error.

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Type provided must be an Enum.
Parameter name: enumType'
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `(enumType.GetType())` should be `enumType`. You are unnecessarily calling `type.GetType()`. Thus, you are getting the type of `Type`, not the type of the enum.

Comment: `enumType` is already a `Type`. `enumType.GetType()` will result in `typeof(Type)`, not `typeof(Color)`.

Comment: `this T enumType` should be changed to `this Type enumType` and `Enum.GetValues(enumType);`

Comment: Note the debugger or `Immediate Window` is great for working through these kinds of issues. When the exception is thrown, type in `?enumType.GetType()` in the `Immediate Window`, and you'll soon spot your mistake.

Comment: You need to remove <T>

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the extension an `Enum` value, but with a `Type` value. When you are using generic type arguments, you do not operate with types (you use reflection for that), but with values *of that type*. Since

`Color.Blue` is of type `Color`

and

`typeof(Color)` is of type `Type`,

your code will work fine when you call it like this:

```
Color.Blue.ToCombo()
```

or

```
default(Color).ToCombo()
```

Or you just use reflection by working directly with the type...

```
public void ToCombo(this Type enumType)
{
    var v = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
}
```

And keep your initial call.

Answer (score -1):

In `typeof(Color).ToCombo()` you are getting extention methods not for a `Color` type, which is simply not possible, but you are extending `Type` type, so you are trying to call

`Enum.GetValues()` on a `Type` not `Enum`, so it will eventually die at runtime.

You have to add a check for generic specifications, allowing only enum types, and fix code below:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var results = ToCombo(typeof(Color));
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> ToCombo(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsEnum)
            {
                return ((Color[])Enum.GetValues(type)).Select(_=>_.ToString());
            }
            return Array.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest considering the below approach.

*I have also assumed the point of the method is to **return** the values to be inserted into the `combo`, so I have changed from `void` to `List<T>`.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public enum Color
    {
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue
    }
    public static class EnumCombo
    {
        public static List<T> ToCombo<T>()
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList();
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var results = EnumCombo.ToCombo<Color>();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I am explicitly **not** using an extension method, since an extension method approach tends to be more verbose (since you would need to make a call either on the `Type` of the enum, but still pass the `enum` type as the `T` parameter, or you'd need to pass through an actual `enum` value - both of which are slightly less clear in my view).

Answer (score -1):

Your extension method needs to change to :

```
  public static void ToCombo<T>(this T type)
    {
        if (typeof(T).BaseType != typeof(Enum))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }
        var arrValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
    }
```

Comment: Enums as internal value type, can't be extended using extension method, so it will not compile